# CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Getting the below error in when trying to run the application

> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Jamez do you know the answer of it

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer of the question either remove the NDK or update it.